# Agregar datos a JSONArray

Tags: java, jsonobject

Necesito agregar a este resultado, en cada posición unos datos que tengo en `json.getJSONObject(l)` al final de los que ya tengo.

Pero según lo que tengo lo que hace es reemplazarme los datos que ya existen en `datosReserva.getJSONArray("lineas");` la posición que elijo (l).

Este es mi código

```
JSONObject desglosePrecios = obtenerDesglosePrecios(localizador, afilage, usuario.getCodigousu(), usuario.getClausu(), usuario.getAfilusu(), datosReserva.getString("secacc"), datosReserva.getString("integrCamDiv"));
    datosReserva.put("desglosePrecios", desglosePrecios);
    JSONObject obj = datosReserva.getJSONObject("desglosePrecios");
    JSONArray json = obj.getJSONArray("desgloseLineas");
    JSONArray lineas = datosReserva.getJSONArray("lineas");
    JSONArray linea = new JSONArray();
    for (int l = 0; l < lineas.length(); l++) {
            linea.put(json.getJSONObject(l));
            lineas.put(l, linea.getJSONObject(l));
    }
```

Cuando los agrego, los reemplaza:
[image: Datos]

Comment: Seria de mucha ayuda si vas a un creador de json en internet y creas un ejemplo o muestras el resultado del web service si es que lo hay, es decir el json que quieres recorrer, de esa manera entendemos que debes hacer o que haces mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución con:

```
for (int l = 0; l < lineas.length(); l++) {
        lineas.getJSONObject(l).put("importe_aumentado", json.getJSONObject(l).getString("importe_aumentado"));
        lineas.getJSONObject(l).put("importe_hotel", json.getJSONObject(l).getString("importe_hotel"));
        lineas.getJSONObject(l).put("porcent_iva", json.getJSONObject(l).getString("porcent_iva"));
        lineas.getJSONObject(l).put("ivaInc", json.getJSONObject(l).getBoolean("ivaInc"));
    }
```

Lo dejo por aquí por si luego alguien lo necesita.