# Agregar datos a JSONArray comparando datos

Tags: java, jsonarray, jsonobject

Según el caso que presentaba antes como inquietud...
[Agregar datos a JSONArray](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197751/agregar-datos-a-jsonarray/197845#197845)

Ahora bien, para esto mismo

```
for (int l = 0; l < lineas.length(); l++) {
    lineas.getJSONObject(l).put("importe_aumentado", json.getJSONObject(l).getString("importe_aumentado"));
    lineas.getJSONObject(l).put("importe_hotel", json.getJSONObject(l).getString("importe_hotel"));
    lineas.getJSONObject(l).put("porcent_iva", json.getJSONObject(l).getString("porcent_iva"));
    lineas.getJSONObject(l).put("ivaInc", json.getJSONObject(l).getBoolean("ivaInc"));
}
```

Tengo que hacer que esto funcione cuando me vienen varias lineas, tengo que unir mis dos objetos pero la posicion de mi json.getJSONObject() tendra que ser comparando un campo que tengo en lineas.getJSONObject() que se llama numero y en json.getJSONObject() que se llama num_linea. Esto porque no necesariamente la información que quiero agregar esta en la posición de mi json.getJSONObject() es la misma que lineas.getJSONObject().

json.getJSONObject().getString("num_linea"))

Debe ser igual a

lineas.getJSONObject().getString("numero"))

Para que se agreguen los datos correctos.

Comment: Podrías incluir tu JSON en la pregunta? Así nos orientamos mejor y podemos ayudarte =)

Comment: Ya fue incluido

Answer (score 1):

Intente con:

```
JSONArray json = obj.getJSONArray("desgloseLineas");
        JSONArray lineas = datosReserva.getJSONArray("lineas");
        for (int j = 0; j < json.length(); j++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < lineas.length(); l++) {
                if (json.getJSONObject(j).getString("num_lineas").equals(lineas.getJSONObject(l).getString("numero"))) {
                    lineas.getJSONObject(l).put("importe_aumentado", json.getJSONObject(j).getDouble("importe_aumentado"));
                    lineas.getJSONObject(l).put("importe_hotel", json.getJSONObject(j).getDouble("importe_hotel"));
                    lineas.getJSONObject(l).put("porcent_iva", json.getJSONObject(j).getString("porcent_iva"));
                    lineas.getJSONObject(l).put("ivaInc", json.getJSONObject(j).getBoolean("ivaInc"));
                }
            }
        }
```

Ya que al recorrer al mismo tiempo los dos JSON que tengo puedo comparar con cada uno si existe el dato que me interesa en ambos con:

```
if (json.getJSONObject(j).getString("num_lineas").equals(lineas.getJSONObject(l).getString("numero")))
```

Comment: esta es una respuesta o es parte de tu pregunta?

Comment: Es al solución que encontré

Comment: por favor considera agregar la explicación de como este fragmento de código soluciona el problema, para que le sirva a otros usuarios de referencia

Comment: Gracias, soy nueva por aquí.